# SQL SERVER equivalent of a HashMap?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hashmap

In the Java application, if a table (small one) has to be queried many times one can simply create a HashMap and store the contents of the table in it. Once this is done subsequent calls can be made to the HashMap instead of the table thereby substantially improving the performance of the program.

I have a similar situation in SQL Server where I have to loop say 5,00,00 times in a stored procedure and each time there are many small tables that are queried. Is there a way I can substantially reduce the time taken to execute the procedure by using an equivalent concept in SQL Server?

Comment: Generally set-based processing will perform better than looping in SQL Server. That said, you can use an in-memory table with a hash index to provide efficient lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases have similar functionality, but it is hidden in the page caching mechanisms.  If you repeatedly use a table, then it will be loaded into memory, and memory operations are much faster than disk operations.

I should note that you can explicitly store tables in memory using memory optimized tables (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/introduction-to-memory-optimized-tables)).  Those maintain data integrity for data modifications, if that is necessary for your application.

Further, you should define indexes if you are randomly accessing rows in the table.  Indexes in most databases (including SQL Server) are using binary trees.  The difference in performance between a binary tree and a hashmap -- particularly on a small table -- is not going to significant.

I should note that if your goal is to write the most optimized code possible, then SQL is probably not the right environment.  SQL engines do a lot more than process data, particularly with respect to data management and maintaining data integrity.  This incurs overhead.  For *everything* they do, they are usually quite efficient, but for a particular algorithm, it might be faster to write the logic elsewhere.  (Of course, in a database you get parallelism for free.)